# Python: función que evalué si una matriz es diagonal

Tags: python, matrices

necesito hacer una función que evalúe si una matriz es diagonal. Empecé con esto pero no puedo pensar que número poner dentro de los for como límite, alguien sabe que números tendría que escribir. Gracias.

```
def es_matriz_diagonal(m):
    for i in range(0, ): 
        for j in range(0, ): 
            if ((i != j) and (m[i][j] != 0)): 
                return False  
    return True
```

Comment: Tendrás que poner la dimensión de la matriz. Si quieres ver que una matriz NxN es diagonal el for será de 0 a N-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo vas a iterar por toda la matriz, tiene que poner el rango hasta el número que tienes de columnas y renglones. En esta caso sería:

```
matrix = np.array( [[1, 0, 0],  
              [0, 5, 0],  
              [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0]])

def es_matriz_diagonal(m):
    valor = True
    for i in range(0, m.shape[0]): 
        for j in range(0, m.shape[1]): 
            if (i != j):
                valor = (valor) & (m[i][j] == 0)
                if valor==False:
                    break
    return valor
```

También se puede realizar con paquete `numpy`,

```
import numpy as np

def es_matriz_diagonal_np(m):
    valor = m==np.diag(np.diag(m))
    return ((valor).sum()==m.shape[0]*m.shape[1])
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: También puedes poner `return np.all(valor)`